# Access a private field for a junit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, field

I am trying to initialize a private field from a class in order to unit test its methods. For that I am using reflection but I am always getting an IllegalArgumentException and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

My code looks something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    private BufferedReader reader;

    public void methodToTest(){
        doSomethingwith(reader);
    }

}

public class testClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        Field reader = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("reader");
        reader.setAccessible(true);
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("some string");
        BufferedReader readerToSet = new BufferedReader(stringReader);
        reader.set(readerToSet, readerToSet);
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();
        instance.methodToTest();
    }

}
```

I get this error when I am trying to run the test:

```
Can not set java.io.BufferedReader field MyClass.receiveReader to java.io.BufferedReader
```

I also tried getting the value of the field from the class and setting to the reader. But the value returns null and I still get the same error message.

Any idea how I could initialize the field so I can test the method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must instantiate the object *before* you can set its field! (And you have misspelled the BufferedReader reference.)

```
Field reader = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("reader");
reader.setAccessible(true);
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("some string");
BufferedReader readerToSet = new BufferedReader(stringReader);
reader.set(mc, readerToSet);
mc.methodToTest();
```

Answer (score 42):

You can also use spring-test if you are using spring.

```
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

ReflectionTestUtils.setField(notificationService, "timeToLive", 90L);
```

Answer (score 13):

Using apache.commons.lang3

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;

FieldUtils.writeField(myObject, "anyProperty", 420/*any value*/, true);

FieldUtils.readField(myObject, "anyProperty", true);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Mockito for that (org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.Whitebox)

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(object, "fieldName", fieldValue);
```

Comment: Whitebox was in the `internal` package of Mockito and doesn't work anymore since `Mockito 2.6.2`. You could use `org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.FieldSetter` instead, but that is also in the `internal` package. It seems that Mockito doesn't want you to manipulate private fields, but internally these methods do the same thing as the solution from [@laune](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27857778/426371)

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @kocko is correct for most cases. But if you do not want to show implementation details, you can just do not set access level modifier to your field (`default` access level).

So in your case field declaration should look like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    BufferedReader reader;
    ...
}
```

And then make sure your test is located in same package with your code, but in `test` directory. If all is done right, you will be able to access it with out any hacks.

Note: `default` access level means that the thing is visible only inside class and package.

Comment: I see no answer by a @kocko