# Spring Controller Unit Test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, controller, junit5

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA, and JUnit 5.

All IDs in entities are automatically generated by DB (`@GeneratedValue`).

So all entities don't include any `constructors` and `setter methods` for initializing ID.

When I implement unit tests for controllers (`@WebMvcTest`),
all ids of entities are `null`.

The problem is that some endpoints respond id, so when I implement unit tests for them, they respond `null`, that is, fail the test.

How can I implement unit tests for controllers that respond ID generated by DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Getter methods to class and then use `ObjectMapper` to set id field.

```
Employee employee = new ObjectMapper().readValue(""{\"id\": \"1\"}", Employee.class);
```

Other approach is to use reflection in JUnit to set that field.

```
    Employee employee = new Employee();

    Field field = Employee.class.getDeclaredField("id");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(employee, "1");
```

Other ways to use reflection: [Access a private field for a junit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857612/access-a-private-field-for-a-junit-test)